# How can I exclude partitions when converting CSV to ORC using AWS Glue?

Tags: etl, aws-glue, orc

I have a bunch of CSV files in S3 that I am trying to covert to ORC using an ETL job in AWS Glue. I have a crawler that crawls the directory containing the CSVs and generates a table. The table looks like this:

```
Column name | Data type | Partition key
---------------------------------------
field1      | string    |
field2      | string    |
field3      | string    |
partition_0 | string    | Partition (0)
partition_1 | string    | Partition (1)
```

Next, I try to convert the CSVs into ORC files. Here is a similar ETL script to what I'm using:

```
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 'database', 'table_name', 'output_dir'])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
partition_predicate = '(partition_0 = "val1") AND (partition_1 = "val2")'
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = args['database'], table_name = args['table_name'], push_down_predicate = partition_predicate, transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
final = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = datasource0, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = { "path": args['output_dir'] }, format = "orc")
job.commit()
```

I have another crawler that crawls my output directory containing the ORC files. When it generates the table, it looks like this:

```
Column name | Data type | Partition key
---------------------------------------
field1      | string    |
field2      | string    |
field3      | string    |
partition_0 | string    |
partition_1 | string    |
partition_0 | string    | Partition (0)
partition_1 | string    | Partition (1)
```

It looks like it considers the partitions to be fields in the ORC file (which they should not be). How can I modify my script so that the CSV to ORC conversion won't include the partition keys as schema columns?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to preserve partitioning then add option `partitionKeys` to the writer:

```
final = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = datasource0, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = { "path": args['output_dir'], "partitionKeys" -> Seq("partition_0", "partition_1") }, format = "orc")
```

Otherwise just remove partitioning columns:

```
cleanDyf = datasource0.dropFields(Seq("partition_0", "partition_1"))
final = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = cleanDyf, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = { "path": args['output_dir'] }, format = "orc")
```